# Replace new lines of a code string with <ol="1"> using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace() function to replace new lines in my code string with ol tag of html to display the following string :

```
 <h2>Hello world</h2>
 This is a new line.

 This is also a new line. I am not a new line.
```

as

```
 1. <h2>Hello world</h2>
 2. This is a new line.
 3. .....blank line....
 4. This is also a new line. I am not a new line.
```

The code bellow matches new lines, and replaces them,

```
 echo preg_replace("/(\n+)([^\n]+)/","<ol start='0'><li>$1$2</li></ol>",$code);
```

it returns the wired output

```
 0. <h2>Hello world</h2>
 0. This is a new line.
 0. .....blank line....
 0. This is also a new line. I am not a new line.
```

so i thought i would change "0" to "1" in ol tag

then the result was

```
 1. <h2>Hello world</h2>
 1. This is a new line.
 1. .....blank line....
 1. This is also a new line. I am not a new line.
```

How can I get my expected output ?

please help.

Answer (score 1):

As you need to do basic logic (a counter) a way to archive this is by using the `preg_replace_callback` function like on this example:

```
<?php

$text = "<h2>Hello world</h2>\nThis is a new line.\n\nThis is also a new line. I am not a new line.\n";

print "\nBEFORE:\n$text";

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/([^\n]*)(\n)/',
    function ($matches) {
        global $number;
        return "<ol start='" . ++$number . "'><li>" . $matches[1] . "</li></ol>\n";
    },
    $text
);

print "\nAFTER:\n$text";
```

More information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php